# How to write a macro to turn a list of tuples into a Vec of Complex numbers

Tags: rust, macros

I've go a lot of unit tests to write which rely on lists of complex numbers. (Crate num-complex = "0.4.0").

I'd like to be able to initialize Vecs of `Complex<F:Float>` with as little boilerplate as possible.

I was thinking it could be like the `vec![]` macro except a bit more specialized, i.e. that it would consume tuples of Float and return a `Vec<Complex<f64>>`.  I suppose the syntax would be like:

```
let v: Vec<Complex<f64>> = vec_cplx![(0.0,-25.0), (0.0, -9.0)]
```

It would be nice if the Float type were generic, but not really necessary since I use only f64s at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```rust
use num::Complex;

macro_rules! vec_cplx {
    ($(($re:expr, $im:expr)),*) => {
        vec![$(Complex::new($re, $im)),*]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Complex<f32>> = vec_cplx![(0.0, -25.0), (0.0, -9.0)];
    dbg!(v);
    let v: Vec<Complex<f64>> = vec_cplx![(0.0, -25.0), (0.0, -9.0)];
    dbg!(v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a24e67829858d1587c42f3360864908)

This will work with any type that `Complex::new()` accepts since it's a macro and the type checking happens after macro expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you need a dedicated macro?

I would simply map and collect a literal array of tuples.

Or maybe a function doing so would be sufficient?

```rust
use num_complex::Complex;
use num_traits::float::Float;

fn vec_cplx<F: Float, const N: usize>(
    tuples: [(F, F); N]
) -> Vec<Complex<F>> {
    tuples
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(re, im)| Complex { re, im })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v1_f64: Vec<Complex<f64>> = [(1.1, 2.2), (3.3, 4.4), (5.5, 6.6)]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(re, im)| Complex { re, im })
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", v1_f64);
    //
    let v1_f32: Vec<Complex<f32>> = [(1.1, 2.2), (3.3, 4.4), (5.5, 6.6)]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(re, im)| Complex { re, im })
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", v1_f32);
    //
    let v2_f64: Vec<Complex<f64>> =
        vec_cplx([(1.1, 2.2), (3.3, 4.4), (5.5, 6.6)]);
    println!("{:?}", v2_f64);
    //
    let v2_f32: Vec<Complex<f32>> =
        vec_cplx([(1.1, 2.2), (3.3, 4.4), (5.5, 6.6)]);
    println!("{:?}", v2_f32);
}
```

Comment: This is legit, and I'm doing something like this right now, but my arrays are so numerous that I want to reduce the boilerplate as much as possible.  Thanks for the effort you put into your answer.

Comment: @pnadeau Ah? Where is the boilerplate in calling `vec_cplx([ ... ])` vs calling `vec_cplx![ ... ]`? One `!` turned into `(` and one `)` added at the end? Is that so important? If this function relies on what you already do, then it will be easy to maintain and modify according to your needs; on the other hand, you have to deal with and eventually maintain a macro that you found very hard to produce in the first place.

Comment: Good points on maintaining the macro.  Sorry I misread your answer.  It leads with the 'unfolded version' and I thought that was what you were proposing.  You function based version is just as compact as the macro.  Given that I did ask for a macro, for better or worse, I approved the other answer which provided one.